# Apache doesn't start background in windows

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file, cmd

I want to run the apache in a background.

**apache-start.bat** file:

```
@echo off
cd C:\wnmp\bin\apache\bin\
@start /b "apache" "httpd.exe"
exit
```

apache is works fine when i run this this bat file. but Command line window is still appear. when i close that window apache will stop. i want to run in background.

OS:windows 10(Technical Preview)

Apache: 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rather need to tun the apache as a service: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#winsvc

There a lot of ways to start a hidden process from batch though:
https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way